# Tyrus server endpoint @OnMessage method not triggered

Tags: java, websocket, java-7, tyrus

I am attempting to run a simple websocket example using Tyrus 1.8.3 and the javax.websocket API, following https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api/ as a guide.

Using annotations, I have created a simple server endpoint and a client endpoint which triggers a method annotated with@OnOpen correctly.  However, when I send a message from the client, the method with @OnMessage is not triggered on the server side.

Interestingly, the session id created at onOpen differs between the client and server.  I don't understand why and think this may be something to do with the problem?  Should the session ids not be the same - there is only one session...

I have also written a simple Javascript client to connect to the same server endpoint and this also does not trigger the @OnMessage method, so I am suspecting there is an issue on the server side.

I have raised the log level to FINE as nothing is reported at INFO level.  From the logs it looks like the websocket upgrade is successful and the connection is opened OK.  A `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException` is thrown on both client and server but I'm not sure if this is relevant...

I have uploaded all of the code to github here: https://github.com/stephenhartley/websocket-demo
The logs files can be viewed in the logs folder.

Could anyone give me some guidance how to trace the cause of this issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: which JDK are you using? I tried JDK 1.7 and 1.8 and both are working for me. (I see that onMessage on the server side was invoked).

Comment: I'm using a 1.7 JDK....  Out of interest, am I right in saying that the logged session id should be the same on client and server?

Comment: no, you are not; session id is just LOCAL identifier, not included in websocket protocol definition.

Comment: about the JDK - can you share more? OS/specific version/...? I used 1.7.0_72 on Mac (10.10.1, but that hopefully should not matter).

Comment: java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
running on Windows 7

Comment: Can you update and try again? From what I know, these early versions of Java 7 had some issues and you might be hitting one of them.

Comment: I'm now using  
  
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: @Pavel Bucek
I'm now using up to date version of JDK:
  
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)

...but still get the same problem.  Logs files look identical, uploaded to github at https://github.com/stephenhartley/websocket-demo/tree/master/logs/jdk1.7.0_72 for reference.

Comment: I cloned https://github.com/shekhargulati/wordgame which is the original author's codebase and the @OnMessage method is not triggered in that demo code either...

Comment: Can (any of you) please file a bug against Tyrus? I need to take closer look (https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS). Anyway, if you can share more information about your environment (proxies etc) + tcp dump or similar info, it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like I have permission to create an issue on that JIRA - my java.net username is stephenhartley  Thanks

Comment: Make sure you are logged in. If it still doesn't work, please try to clear java.net cookies etc and try again.

Comment: Created issue TYRUS-390 to track this.